# Disabled "uninstall" button in Programs and Features

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I wrote a program with Visual Studio (C#) and used [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create an installer. But somewhere in the middle of my numerous tests, I ended up in a state where I cannot uninstall my program through the `Programs and Features` panel.

Here's what it shows:

[image]

As you can see, the `Change`and `Uninstall` buttons are disabled and prevent me from uninstalling my program.

I tried many things:

- rebooting
- rebooting in safe mode
- `appwiz.cpl` (my program doesn't
  appear in it)
- CCleaner
- Microsoft's troubleshooter (found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed))
- Delete all occurrences of my program with Regedit
- Delete the install folder in `Program Files (x86)`

But the issue remains...

It is to note that the troubleshooter said it fixed the issue, then stopped showing my program in its uninstall list (although my problem is still there).

What should I do?

How does `Programs and Features` build its program's list since my program doesn't show up in `appwiz.cpl`?

Comment: Look under:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` depending if it's 32-bit on 64 or native.

Comment: I already checked everywhere with Regedit (searched and removes all occurrences of my program). But I've just had another look and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @p._phidot_, I tried [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) but to no avail.
Then, I tried other uninstallers that did not work either ([Wise Program Uninstaller](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-program-uninstaller.html) and [Absolute Uninstaller](https://www.glarysoft.com/absolute-uninstaller/).

But finally, I found my Grail in [Ashampoo Uninstaller](https://www.ashampoo.com/fr/eur/pin/1603/systemsoftware/uninstaller-7).
I don't know how it did it, but it was the only one able to find the remnants of my program and to actually delete them. My program does not appear anymore in `Programs and Features`. Problem solved.

EDIT: The report at the end of the process said that one registry key was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Revo Uninstaller.. If the installed app is not listed.. you may try the 'hunter mode' .  ( :